# How to know length and width to set?

Tags: java, user-interface, width

Just began GUI programming a few days ago and I am wondering how I know what dimensions to give my window and the objects inside of it. I know in my head what I want them to look like but I am just not sure how to know the measurements. Any tips?

Comment: You might want to take a look at Oracle's JavaFX Scene Builder :)

Comment: Whether you're using [Java Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) or [JavaFX](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javase-clienttechnologies.htm), the placement and sizing of containers and the components you put within them falls in the domain of [layout managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html). I cannot emphasize this enough: *Do the reading* - learn how they work, and they'll be your best friend. Don't, and they'll lead you to early baldness...

Comment: @jah Whats the difference between Java Swing and Java FX?

Answer (score 0):

Modern UI programming does not normally involve setting exact measurements of components in a window.  You need to read a basic tutorial on Java Layout Managers; the basic idea is that you use the layout manager to arrange things so that they are lined up the way you want and stretch the way you want when the window's size is changed by the user.  You put the components in the places that achieves the overall topological shape that you want, and you don't set a specific size.

Good luck.

Comment: I am practicing with the layout managers and have a book. I decided that I wanted to make a calculator that looked like one that comes with every windows computer but I can't figure out how to use the layout managers properly so it will look how I want. Do you know any good tutorials?

Comment: You can start with the one Oracle has, at least.  It seems to me what most of the tutorials miss is how to use the various layout managers once you've learned what they do.  The Win7 calculator has a fixed size (unlike most programs), upper section is a display-only text box, then there are buttons below that in a grid.  There's also a menu at the top.  I'd look at using BorderLayout to put the upper text area and a panel with the buttons below it (North and Center), and GroupLayout for the panel with the buttons - GridLayout won't do the double-height "=" button.  Good exercise.